# How can the auto updater wait for an event from the launcher executable?

Tags: install4j

I am using an updater application (without version check) in unattended mode, but I need the updater to wait for an event from the launcher executable before continuing to execute the installer.

The event will typically be a user confirmation that the downloaded installer can be executed. I would prefer that the launcher executable prompt the user to update, once it knows that the downloaded installer is ready.

Is there another way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such communication mechanism as of install4j 6.1.

I would recommend to change your updater application so that it does not execute the installer but just writes it to a particular directory. After it has finished you can check if an executable exists in the directory and ask if it should be executed. If the user confirms the update, you then invoke another custom installer application that only contains the "Run executable" action from the original updater template.

Comment: Thanks, would it be a good idea to add something like this as a template application?

Comment: We don't want to add to many templates for the updaters with slightly different functionality. Custom installer applications are fully configurable just like the installer, so you can add any combination of screens and actions to it for an unlimited number of use cases.